# Jenkins Trigger with choice param

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

I am trying to create a trigger which would poll my scm and run a job with a specified parameter.

I have a choiceParam.

```
        parameters {
            choiceParam('MY_PARAM', ['param1', 'param2', 'param3'], 'My param')
        }
```

And I would like to the job to be triggered automatically always with the same choiceParam(for instance with param1)

Is it possible? If so how?

```
        triggers {
            scm "*/10 * * * *"
            parameters {
                What should be here????
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

As I have checked, choice params list default value is the first one. So in my scenario it would be param1.

```
    triggers {
        scm "*/10 * * * *"
    }
```

So that situation would automatically run with param1

Answer (score 0):

Choice parameters are nothing but string parameters under the hood. So you would call it like this:

```
parameters {
    string(name: "MY_PARAM", value: "param1")
}
```

Comment: Such change would include additional param on my jenkins site. I don't want to have it visible.